# ResearchGate: removing wrong uploaded article without affecting no. reads/citations

Tags: publications

I recently noticed that the wrong article was uploaded to ResearchGate by a co-author several years ago (the title describes the article from a conference proceedings, but the uploaded paper was a journal article). It has a number of citations and reads.

I want to remove the wrongly uploaded journal article and upload the correct conference article, but I am not sure if removing the journal article will remove the no. of reads and citations that the paper has received over the years. Does removing the article also remove the no. of reads and citations?

Comment: I’m not familiar with their system, but why would you want to? Those people citing that paper are citing the paper as it currently exists. If you change the paper those citations are pointing to, you’d risk confusing anyone who follows the citation trail.